# `String#===` documentation example

Tags: ruby, string, equality

The string class documentation (2.1.1) describes the `===` operator as:

> If `obj` is not an instance of `String` but responds to `to_str`, then the two strings are compared using case equality `Object#===`.

I tried this in one example, but it doesn't work. Here is how I tried it:

```
class Foo
  def to_str
    'some_txt'
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
'some_txt' === foo #=> false
```

I expected that this should return `true`. But it isn't. I'm asking if someone can show this description in an example. What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If obj is not an instance of String but responds to to_str, then the two strings are compared using case equality Object#===.

In your case `foo` responds to `#to_str`, but not an instance of `String`. So the `'some_txt' === foo` is actually using [`Object#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)

> *Case Equality* – For class `Object`, effectively the same as calling `#==`, but typically overridden by descendants to provide meaningful semantics in case statements.

`Foo` is a **descendant class** of `Object`. Any class in Ruby by default *inherits* from `Object`. Now `Foo` didn't override the method `#===`, so as per the documentation, it will use [`Object#==`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F) method. The documentation of `Object#==` says :

> *Equality* — At the `Object` level, `==` returns *true* only if `obj` and `other` are the **same object**. Typically, this method is overridden in descendant classes to provide class-specific meaning.

According to the above *principle* - As `'some_txt'` instance of `String` and `foo` is an instance of `Foo`, `'some_txt' === foo`(which is actually  `foo == 'some_txt'`, as `Object#===` delegates the call to `Object#==`) is giving `false`.

The documentation of `Object#==` and `Object#===` both says -

> Typically, this method is overridden in descendant classes to provide class-specific meaning.

That means you can override either `Object#===` or `Object#==` to implement your logic of comparisons. Just to simulate what I just said, I am putting one dummy example code :-

```
class Foo
  def to_str
    'some_txt'
  end

  def ==(other)
    true
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
'some_txt' === foo # => true
foo.class.superclass # => Object
```

Comment: You could implement `Foo#==` to override `Object#==`

Comment: You probably have the correct reasoning in your mind, but your presentation order does not work logically. You want to show that in this case, `'some_txt' === foo` is using `Object#===` (not `Object#==`), and  then you want to show that `Object#===` is using `Object#==` unless it is overridden.

Comment: My misunderstand was that I didn't see that  Object#=== is a method of object not of string.. thx

Comment: @sawa Can you review now?

Comment: @sawa Thanks for your all comments to make this answer readable.. :)